# Chart Auto Scroll (Oscilloscope Effect)

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, mschart

My issue is that whenever I add a point to the chart, it compresses all the points. Instead, I want it to auto scroll.

Here are two .gifs to explain what my issue is

**What I have now**

[image]

**What I want to achieve**

[image]

The code I have right now is

```
    DateTime dt;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = DateTime.Now;
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            chart1.Series["Light"].Points.AddXY(dt.ToShortTimeString(), 1);
        }
        else
        {
            chart1.Series["Light"].Points.AddXY(dt.ToShortTimeString(), 0);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You have to remove one point from the left each time you add 1 point to the right. This way you keep the same amount of information at a time, but you just move it by some offset.

Comment: @FCin Could you give me the code to remove a point from the left? I couldn't figure that one out

Comment: `chart1.Series["Light"].Points` is a list. Look for a method for removing elements from list. That is all you need.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have a choice of options:

- You can remove a point from the left for each point you add to the right (after a certain number)
- You can shift the x-Axis `Minimum` and `Maximum` values
- You can set the chart to zoom&pan and then pan, i.e. move the `ScaleView`

The first option is simple and will keep the number of DataPoints constant. This may be good or bad, depending on your needs.

The other two will keep the collection of points and only pan in the chart.

Common references:

```
ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];
Series s = chart.Series[0];
```

Here is code for the 1st option:

```
s.Points.AddXY(..);
s.Points.RemoveAt(0);
ca.AxisX.Minimum = double.NaN;
ca.AxisX.Maximum = double.NaN;
ca.RecalculateAxesScale();
```

Here is code for option 2:

```
int ix = s.Points.AddXY(..);

ca.AxisX.Maximum  = s.Points[ix].XValue;
ca.AxisX.Minimum += s.Points[ix].XValue - s.Points[ix-1].XValue;
ca.RecalculateAxesScale();
```

Here is code for option 3:

```
int ix = s.Points.AddXY(..);
ca.AxisX.Minimum = double.NaN;
ca.AxisX.Maximum = double.NaN;
ca.RecalculateAxesScale();

ca.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(s.Points[ix-pointMax ].XValue, s.Points[ix].XValue );
```

This assumes there are `pointMax` points already in the series.

All examples assume you have already a few points. Options 1&3 also assume neither `Minimum` nor `Maximum` of the x-axis are set, i.e. they are `double.NaN`.

The last option will let you scroll around the data conveniently.

The 1st one keeps the data points count low but loses all but the last points.

Let's watch all options at work:

[image]

Do note that options 2&3 also assume that you have valid x-values. If you don't, you need to make the x-axis indexed and use the point index instead of the values.

Comment: tysm!! Best answer I had since i joined stack overflow :)