# How to adjust MSChart scrollBar

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, mschart

For a chart I have created a scroll bar which enables itself when the X Axis data points reaches a specific limit.

The problem which I'm facing is that the scroll is working in opposite direction [my chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUTD7.gif), hiding the new data points.

Here is the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076045/chart-auto-scroll-oscilloscope-effect/50077332#50077332) of the effect which I want to achieve.

My code snippet:

```
int ix = chartTrend.Series["Ok Parts"].Points.AddXY(process.time, process.okCount);
            
if (chartTrend.Series["Ok Parts"].Points.Count > 8)
{
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = double.NaN;
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = double.NaN;
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView
              .Zoom(chartTrend.Series["Ok Parts"].Points[ix - 8 ].XValue, 
                    chartTrend.Series["Ok Parts"].Points[ix].XValue);
```

Comment: Did you set the DateTimeIntervalType for the series? You may want to try using [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axisscaleview.zoom?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataVisualization_Charting_AxisScaleView_Zoom_System_Double_System_Double_System_Windows_Forms_DataVisualization_Charting_DateTimeIntervalType_)

Comment: Hello @TaW thank you so much, the time interval is in seconds and I have set the value of DateTimeIntervalType to 8 as mentioned in the documentation but still I'm facing the same issue, may be you can guide me on how to do it correctly